# Error fetchin' ATI Driver 64 bit

Tags: 10.10, 64-bit

Whenever i try to install the ATI 64Bit drivers from jockey this comes up

> Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc6-i386_2.12.1-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package list is obsolete and the old package is removed from the repositories. Refreshyour packages list and try it again.

The command for refreshig the packages list is:

```
sudo apt-get update
```